# Proving concave function

Tags: analysis

Given a function $f : [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ with $f(t) = ln(1+t)$ for all $t \in [0,\infty)$. Prove by definition that $f$ is concave.

Comment: Do you know the definition of “concave”? Can you check it for this function?

Comment: It is nor easy to prove it from the definition. Can you show  your proof?  @MPW

Comment: No, i got stuck also

Answer (score 1):

$f'(t)=\frac 1 {1+t}$ and $f''(t)=-\frac 1 {(1+t)^{2}} <0$.Hence $f$ is concave.

Comment: Thank you, but how to prove it by definition?

Comment: @asrida There is no simple proof of this starting with from the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following definition of $\log$:
$$\log(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t.$$
We can use this to prove concavity of $\log$ on $[1, \infty)$, which is equivalent to your request. We have, for $x \ge y \ge 1$ and $\lambda \in (0, 1]$,
\begin{align}
&\log(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) y) - \lambda \log x - (1 - \lambda) \log y \\
= \, &\int_1^{y + \lambda(x - y)} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t - \lambda \left(\int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t - \int_1^y \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t\right) - \int_1^y \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
= \, &\int_y^{y + \lambda(x - y)} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t - \lambda \int_y^x \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t \\
= \, &\int_0^{x - y} \frac{1}{\lambda a + y} \lambda \,\mathrm{d}a - \lambda \int_0^{x - y} \frac{1}{b + y} \,\mathrm{d}b & \text{where }a = \frac{t - y}{\lambda}, b = t - y\\
= \, &\lambda \int_0^{x - y} \left(\frac{1}{\lambda t + y} - \frac{1}{t + y}\right) \,\mathrm{d}t \ge 0.
\end{align}